# Inserting a variable into Redirect::to in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect

I want to Redirect::to a custom url using a variable in laravel, once I've done some operations. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Route::get('remove_comment/{id}', function($id) {
    $comment = get_comment($id);
    $postId = $comment->Post_Id;
    remove_comment($id);

    return Redirect::to(url('page/{{{$postId}}}'));
});
```

So I want it to redirect to a page with a URL like /post/1 or similar. It doesn't work, how I've implemented it but I'm sure there would be a way. Is it possible to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Try this: `return Redirect::to(url('page/'.$postId));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're inside of your routes, so using Blade won't work unless specified. Also, it's already in PHP so do it like this:

```
Route::get('remove_comment/{id}', function($id) {
    $comment = get_comment($id);
    $postId = $comment->Post_Id;
    remove_comment($id);

    return Redirect::to(url('page/'.$postId));
});
```

Take note of this line: `return Redirect::to(url('page/'.$postId));`

You can also inject a variable into a string using double quotes instead of single quote and wrapping your variable in braces. So:
`return Redirect::to(url("page/{$postId}"));`